# Spring Security Anonymous Authentication not initialised

Tags: java, spring-security, anonymous, spring-4

I am using Spring4 with Spring Security 3.2.4.
I have some http configurations in my security configuration in order to host form based authentication and `REST services` (with authentication) together.

For the pages and REST services which require app-authentication everything works fine with my current configuration but for the pages which does not require authentication, such as login and register, the anonymous authentication is not initialised somehow. Speaking in Java:
`SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() returns null`.

I expect that anonymous authentication is initialised as the documentation (http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#introduction) refers:
Anonymous authentication support is provided automatically when using the HTTP configuration Spring Security 3.0 and can be customized (or disabled) using the  element. You don’t need to configure the beans described here unless you are using traditional bean configuration.

Does anyone have an idea why does it not happen although the documentation refers? (Beside the fact, that the documentation for 3.2.4 refers to 3.0 version and some of the given configuration suggestions refer deprecated implementation)

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I found a workaround:

`@Bean
  public AnonymousAuthenticationFilter anonymousAuthenticationFilter() {
    return new AnonymousAuthenticationFilter("ANONYMOUS", new BasicUserPrincipal("anonymous"),
        AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_ANONYMOUS"));
  }
  @Bean
  public AnonymousAuthenticationProvider anonymousAuthenticationProvider() {
    return new AnonymousAuthenticationProvider("ANONYMOUS");
  }`
@felipe-oriani: did you find a solution?

Comment: That is interesting way with AnonymousAuthenticationFilter. I will try and write my results.